How do I calculate the time between pressing a button?
I need that when the attack button is pressed quickly, the next attack event occurs only after the animation playback ends. This solution looks very good if you don't press the attack button often.
 public void OnAttack(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
 {
     var crit = Random.Range(0.0F, 101.0F);
     
     
     if (crit <= _heroConfig.CrintChance)
     {
         _animController.PlayAnimation(_animator, "Attack02");


     }
     else
     {
         _animController.PlayAnimation(_animator, "Attack01");

     }
         
     
 }

I tried to get the animation time, but I need to specify the name of the animation, which looks very ugly.

You can preven't this by adding a variable for the current state.
private bool _isAttacking = false;

public async void OnAttack(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    // return early if attacking
    if (_isAttacking) return;

    // set state
    _isAttacking = true;

    var crit = Random.Range(0.0F, 101.0F);

    string animationName = crit <= _heroConfig.CrintChance ? "Attack02" : "Attack01";
    _animController.PlayAnimation(_animator, animationName);

    var animationClip = _animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[0].clip;

    // wait for animation to finish
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animationClip.length));

    // reset state
    _isAttacking = false;
}

